# Attach to process programatically succeeds but no debug symbols are loaded

Tags: c, visual-studio, c#-4.0, visual-studio-debugging

I know others have asked the same or similar question but I cannot find an answer that fits my specific problem.

So here I go.

I programmatically open a new instance of Visual Studio (2013), load a .vcxproj file & attach to process.

This is the code:

```
public static class VisualStudioLauncher
{
    private static DTE dte;

    public static void OpenVisualStudio(string path, string fileName)
    {
        Type visualStudioType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.12.0");
        dte = Activator.CreateInstance(visualStudioType) as DTE;

        if (dte != null)
        {
            dte.MainWindow.Visible = true;
            dte.ExecuteCommand("File.OpenProject", path + fileName);
        }
    }

    public static void AttachToProcess(System.Diagnostics.Process ps)
    {
        DTEProcess processToAttachTo = dte.Debugger.LocalProcesses.Cast<DTEProcess>().FirstOrDefault(process => process.ProcessID == ps.Id);
        if (processToAttachTo != null)
        {
            processToAttachTo.Attach();
        }
    }
}
```

I have debugged and made sure that the correct process are attached.

When I set a break point in a source file I get:
*The break point will not be currently hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.*

If I click on the Stop Debugging button and then manually attach to the process I have no problems to set a break point.

1. Does the debug symbols not get loaded when attached programmatically?
2. Could it be that the Code Types is not properly set when attach to process is done programmatically? The settings are : Managed (v4.5, v4.0) and Native.

I have no idea how to solve the above programmatically?

I am happy for any input & help I can get. If you lack any information please let me know.

Comment: this is C++ code,   'C' does not have `class`es. nor `public`  please remove the 'c#' tag and the 'c' tag and insert the 'c++' tag

Comment: are you remembering to compile/link with the `-g` and/or for the debug target?

Comment: This is C# code user3629249. Why would I possibly state that the code is C# if it was not. If you cannot give me some constructive feedback & help, please do not comment.

Comment: In my text above I explicitly state that it is possible to debug the code user3629249.